# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_10_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 28, 28)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

> I'm trying to train my Deep Neural Network to recognize handwritten
>   numbers but I keep getting the error stated previously in the title It
>   gives me an error saying: "ValueError: Error when checking input:
>   expected dense_7_input to have 2 dimensions but got array with shape
>   (60000, 28, 28)" and I don't know why. I've checked previous answers
>   to this problem but nothing worked.
>   **New**: So when i try the last piece of the code it gives me this error:
>   **ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target >arrays. Found 60000 input samples and 10000 target samples.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV6qe.png)

```
# Imports
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import to_categorical

# Configuration options
feature_vector_length = 784
num_classes = 60000

# Load the data
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# Reshape the data - MLPs do not understand such things as '2D'.
# Reshape to 28 x 28 pixels = 784 features
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], feature_vector_length)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], feature_vector_length)

# Convert into greyscale
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

# Convert target classes to categorical ones
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes)

# Imports
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import to_categorical

# Configuration options
feature_vector_length = 784
num_classes = 60000

# Load the data
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# Visualize one sample
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(X_train[0], cmap='Greys')
plt.show()

# Set the input shape
input_shape = (feature_vector_length,)
print(f'Feature shape: {input_shape}')

# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(350, input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# Configure the model and start training
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=250, verbose=1, 
validation_split=0.2)

# New one #######
# Test the model after training
test_results = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=1)
print(f'Test results - Loss: {test_results[0]} - Accuracy: 
{test_results[1]}%')
```

Comment: Can you show us how `dense_7_input` is created?

Comment: [Please don't post code/errors as images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2099607)

Comment: If all the layers in your model are only `Dense` layers and you are working on MNIST dataset, then you need to add a `Flatten` layer as the first layer of your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your code and I got it to work. I added the flatten layer which would turn the inputs into a viable format. I also user tensorflow.keras instead of keras because that version is in my opinion better, but you could use it with both. You also had a problem with your types so I changed your X_train and X_test into numpy arrays of type float32.

```
# Imports
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

# Configuration options
feature_vector_length = 784
num_classes = 60000

# Load the data
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# Reshape the data - MLPs do not understand such things as '2D'.
# Reshape to 28 x 28 pixels = 784 features
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], feature_vector_length)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], feature_vector_length)

# Convert into greyscale
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

# Convert target classes to categorical ones
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes)
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes)

# Imports
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
# Configuration options
feature_vector_length = 784
num_classes = 60000

# Load the data
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# Visualize one sample
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(X_train[0], cmap='Greys')
plt.show()

# Set the input shape
input_shape = (feature_vector_length,)
print(f'Feature shape: {input_shape}')
X_train=np.array(X_train,dtype="float32")
X_test=np.array(X_train,dtype="float32")
# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(350, input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# Configure the model and start training

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= 
['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=250, verbose=1, 
validation_split=0.2)
```

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you but I have another question about the code ... If you can help me i would appreciate (its the **New** part)

Comment: I edited the question and added the final part of code but it gives an error (I have written that in the main question)

Comment: could you tell me the size/shape of the x_test and y_test.

Comment: is this what you are asking? # Reshape to 28 x 28 pixels = 784 features                                                       
                        code line1: X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], feature_vector_length)
                        code line2:X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], feature_vector_length)

Comment: @BernardoAugusto please do not use the comments for follow-up questions, especially if the code in question has been modified in any way (including due to a response); you can (and always should) open a new question instead, with the new status and issue.